# Rabbitmq Basic Auth not working when using azure oauth

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, rabbitmq, bitnami

I have installed rabbitmq using the latest Bitnami Helm chart. Since we use azure I have successfully setup Azure oauth2 using the [tutorial here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/oauth2-examples-azure.html).

Rabbitmq has booted successfully, I am able to login with oauth2, however I am unable to login using basic auth. The username and password textboxes no longer show and I simply see the "Click here to login" button

[image]

```
advancedConfiguration: |-
  [
    {rabbit, [
    {auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_oauth2, rabbit_auth_backend_internal]}
    ]},
    {rabbitmq_management, [
      {oauth_enabled, true},
      {oauth_client_id, "xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx"},
      {oauth_provider_url, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"}
  ]},
  {rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2, [
    {resource_server_id, <<"xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-aa8f-xxxxxxx">>},
    {extra_scopes_source, <<"roles">>},
    {key_config, [
      {jwks_url, <<"https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxx-xx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx/discovery/v2.0/keys">>}
    ]}
  ]}
  ].
```

Do you have any tips on how I can keep both basic auth (for apps) and oauth2 - for users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to login with oauth2, however I am unable to login using basic auth

I'm pretty sure that when you enable OAuth for the management plugin, basic auth is disabled for the management UI. You can create your own login page and POST to it, however - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/764